# How to optimize SQL Server query with Filters and Pagination?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I need optimization recommendations (Don't have access to modify index) for this query, I ommited some variable names for security reason, but this is basically my query, it fluctuates around 300 to 900 milliseconds to complete, when I use c# it's  a little faster, but I want to get below the 100 milliseconds. SQL SERVER 2008

any ideas?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].MyProcedure (  
    PARAMETERS!!!
  AS   
 BEGIN  

SET NOCOUNT ON;   


  create  TABLE #SearchTable  
  (  
  TEMP TABLE PARAMETERS!!!
  )  

   insert into #SearchTable (COLUMNS!!!)  

    SELECT DISTINCT  MYDATA!!!
      FROM VIEW!!!  
     WHERE ID =    @ID    
            AND ((( @Variable is  null)            or (VARIABLE LIKE @Variable + '%' ) )
            AND ((( @Variable is  null)            or (VARIABLE LIKE @Variable + '%' ) )
            AND ((( @Variable is  null)            or (VARIABLE LIKE @Variable + '%' ) )
            AND ((( @Variable is  null)            or (VARIABLE LIKE @Variable + '%' ) )
            AND ((( @Variable is  null)            or (VARIABLE LIKE @Variable + '%' ) )
            AND ((( @Variable is  null)            or (VARIABLE LIKE @Variable + '%' ) )



 declare @sql NVARCHAR(max)  
 set @sql = '  
  select * from (  
   select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by '+ @orderBy +') as RowNumber,*   
    from #SearchTable) table
    WHERE (RowNumber > '+ cast(((@CurrentPage -1) * @PageSize) as varchar(max)) +'  
  AND RowNumber <= '+ cast( ((@CurrentPage) * @PageSize) as varchar(max)) +'  
OR ' +  cast( (@PageSize) as varchar(max)) +' = 0)' 

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql

 --exec(@sql)

  select @totalCount = count(*) from #SearchTable  
   print @totalCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry...needed to edit ... that's what you get for "top of head"...

Off the top of the head for pagination, You've already got dynamic sql in place so would go with `'select TOP ' + CAST(@NumberItemsPerPage AS nvarchar(10)) + ' * FROM...WHERE [RowCount] >= ' + CAST((@NumberItemsPerPage * @PageCount) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' AND [RowCount] < ' + CAST((@NumberItemsPerPage * @PageCount)+@NumberItemsPerPage AS nvarchar(10))` as long as you can make sure your order of items is preserved...that should give you the paging aspect.

As for performance, welcome to the wonderful world of trial and error. Indexes, keys and the architecture all come into play so my best advice would be to try different methods of the query, use query analyzer to see if any additional indexes would work...
Dave

Comment: Yeah, there's no other option, trial and error is the only way I guess